# display an element when hovering on another element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want when hovering on yellow box which has the class named `card` the element which is a blue box that has a class named `box` to appear. I have done that in css like this

```
.box {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover + .box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 114px;
  right: 94px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 99px 99px;
}
```

but it didn't work with me what is the problem ?
this is the sandbox link [https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-water-yx1l3g?file=/src/styles.css:336-358[![enter](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-water-yx1l3g?file=/src/styles.css:336-358%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BRAD.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BRAD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  display: none;
 
}

.card:hover .box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 114px;
  right: 94px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 99px 99px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html .box is inside .card element. You're using adjacent sibling selector (+). just use descendant selector. `.card:hover .box`

```css
.card:hover .box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 114px;
  right: 94px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 99px 99px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the plus. Plus target its same sibling element. The box element is the child of the card. So it would be best if you targeted like this.

```
 .card:hover .box {
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     height: 30px;
     width: 40px;
     background-color: blue;
     top: 114px;
     right: 94px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 99px 99px;
    }
```